# How can I fetch a json file using Vapor for my leaf template to show the data?

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a JSON hosted somewhere and I want to fetch the content, put it in a context for my leaf template to read.

However, I cannot make it work. I get the code to compile, but I get an error in the localhost

```
{"error":true,"reason":"Unsupported Media Type"}
```

Can somebody help me please! Happy holidays for all.

```
struct WebsiteController: RouteCollection {
    
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        
        routes.get(use: indexHandler)
        
    }
    
    
    func indexHandler(_ req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<View> {
        return req.client.get("https://streeteasydaily.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/streeteasy1.json").flatMap { res in
            do {
                
                let json = try res.content.decode([Listing].self)
                
                print(json[0].photos[0])
                let context = IndexContext(title: "Homepage", listings: json)
                return try req.view.render("index", context)
            } catch {
                // Handle error
                print("cayo en error")
                return req.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture(error)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct IndexContext: Encodable {
    let title: String
    let listings: [Listing]
}
```

Model

```
final class Listing: Model {
    static let schema = "listings" //basically the table name
    
    @ID
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: "address")
    var address: String
    
    @Field(key: "description")
    var description: String
    
    @Field(key: "photos")
    var photos: [String]
    
    init() {}
    
    //to initialize the db
    init(id: UUID? = nil, address: String, description: String, photos: [String]) {
        self.id = id
        self.address = address
        self.description = description
        self.photos = photos
    }
    

}

//to make acronym conform to CONTENT, and use it in Vapor
extension Listing: Content {}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the JSON? Also, if you remove the json decode attempt and print the response body, do you get what you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the decode is failing to identify all the fields in your JSON to match against those defined in `Listing` and/or the array of such objects. The filenames must match those in the JSON exactly - i.e. case-sensitive and every field in the structure/model must exist in the JSON. Additional fields in the JSON that are not needed/included in the structure/model are fine.